# Using a variable to call specific functions in a bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm fairly new to scripting and could use some help.

I have several scripts on different servers (same OS, different apps), that perform maintenance on filesystems.  I would like to make one large script that I can call from cron with a "variable" that indicates what function(s) should be run.

For instance, almost all the servers experience heap dumps so I'd like that to run on all of them, but each app has different requirements for their specific app so I'd like to pass a variable in cron to tell the script what additional cleanup is required (function).  I have the function part down, just need to know how to call it.

I found some examples that show something like this in cron:

00 23 * * * /home/user/scripts/filesarchive.sh "variable_name"

So I'd like to have cron run the script, but then based on the variable I put in "variable_name" run certain functions within the script.

I can't figure out how to tell the script to take the "variable_name" from the end of the cron command, and then perform the function.

I'm sure it's super easy, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

OS:    RHEL
Shell: Bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use functions.

Try this script with `/home/user/scripts/filesarchive.sh foo` or `/home/user/scripts/filesarchive.sh bar`:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() {
  echo "in foo"
}

bar() {
  echo "in bar"
}

"$1"
```